# Get all elements that are not spans

Tags: javascript, ios, epub, getelementsbytagname

I want a function that gets all elements that are not spans.

Currently I have made a function that gets ALL elements, and also makes an empty array. It then goes through each of the elements, and adds them to the empty array if they are not spans. And returns the (probably no longer empty) array.

Whilst this works, it feels a bit inefficient. I feel it would be better to not even get the spans in the first place, and there must be some way of doing this that I don't know about.

Is there a more efficient way that I can get all elements that are not spans? (this is for epubs displayed in UIWebViews in iOS, and no jquery)

Here is my current code. I apologise if I am doing something stupid, as I'm not a javascript guy:

```
function allElementsExceptSpans()
{
    var result = new Array();
    var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
    for (var i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++)
    {
        if ((allElements[i].tagName != "span")
            && (allElements[i].tagName != "SPAN"))
        {
            result.push(allElements[i]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelector?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FDocument.querySelector) and [friends](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelector?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FDocument.querySelector#See_also) accept a CSS selector as their argument.

```
var not_span = document.querySelectorAll(":not(span)");
```

---

If you wanted to simplify your existing approach, then you could look at using `toLowerCase` instead of two different string comparisons and using `Array.prototype.filter` instead of manually copying the values:

```
function allElementsExceptSpans()
{
    return Array.prototype.filter.call(document.getElementsByTagName("*"), function(element) {
        return element.tagName.toLowerCase() !== "span";
    });
}
```

Comment: Provided your browser supports `:not`, which is a CSS3 thing. IE8 doesn't, for example, and yet IE8 still has a surprising market share. (IE8 is the new IE6! But hopefully not for long.)

Comment: Happiness is a client who doesn't care if things don't look good in IE8 :)

Comment: thanks, well there's something I didn't know about! Is this approach (as written)  going to miss upper case SPANs?

Comment: @narco — HTML element names are case insensitive. It won't be a problem unless you are writing XHTML (which is a pointless exercise in pain for the vast majority of applications these days).

Comment: I should have put in the original question, this is for UIWebViews in iOS only, so no IE. From my quick test so far, this approach seems to work.

Comment: Ah, well I also should have put that it is for epubs, which use XHTML, so how would I go about changing this to deal with potential upper cases?

Comment: If there are `<SPAN>` elements in the XHTML, then the XHTML has errors in it. XHTML is case sensitive and doesn't define `<span>`. If you really had to deal with it, then you'd need something like: `:not(span):not(SPAN)`

Comment: Thanks. Nothing I have seen so far has upper case SPANs in it, however I did previously have an issue somewhere else with upper case tags (they weren't spans). As I said, I'm not normally a javascript guy, so I was just playing it safe, given my lack of knowledge on the subject. Thanks, and thanks for the extra info too.

Comment: Or to be really safe: `:not(span):not(Span):not(sPan):not(SPan):not(spAn):not(SpAn):not(sPAn):not(SPAn):not(spaN)`